# What does "at" symbol enclosed in quotes mean in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file

I've got this code:

```
$filePath = '/blah/image.jpg';
$data_array = array(
  "file_data"=>"@".$filePath,
);
```

the `$data_array = array` construct is an array definition and `"file_data"=>"@".$filePath,` specifies an array element.

The array is then used for setting up an HTTP POST request:

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_array);
```

What does `"@"` in `"@".$filePath` mean?

Comment: It is just a string with an `@` in it. I think the more interesting question would be what you can do with a path that has an `@` prepended....

Comment: <?php echo $data_array['file_data'] ?>

Comment: It is an error control operator in php.

Comment: @abhi: The error control operator is without quotes.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php - `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` - "The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a literal `@` sign being prepended to a string. The result is a value of `@/blah/image.jpg`